# How to adjust the value counts based on a metric?

Tags: pandas

My input is this dataframe :

```
data = {
    'ISSUE': ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6', '#7', '#8', '#9', '#10', '#11', '#12'],
    'CATEGORY': ['CAT1', 'CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3', 'CAT1', 'CAT3', 'CAT3', 'CAT2', 'CAT2', 'CAT2', 'CAT4', 'CAT5'],
    'AGENT': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
    'STATUS': ['FINISHED'] * 12
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   ISSUE CATEGORY AGENT    STATUS
0     #1     CAT1     A  FINISHED
1     #2     CAT1     A  FINISHED
2     #3     CAT2     B  FINISHED
3     #4     CAT3     A  FINISHED
4     #5     CAT1     C  FINISHED
5     #6     CAT3     C  FINISHED
6     #7     CAT3     A  FINISHED
7     #8     CAT2     A  FINISHED
8     #9     CAT2     B  FINISHED
9    #10     CAT2     C  FINISHED
10   #11     CAT4     C  FINISHED
11   #12     CAT5     A  FINISHED
```

Each category has a complexity of resolution time :

```
# EASY  (around 10 mins) :  CAT1+CAT3+CAT5
# MEDIUM (around 2 hours) : CAT2
# HARD  (>= 1 day) : CAT4
```

When using a value counts I got this :

```
AGENT
A    6
C    4
B    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

For example one that interpret these values might think that Agent `A` is the most productive one. It could be but we need to verify that.

For that I started making a code but ignore how to purse so I can readjust the value counts :

```
complexity = {
    'CAT1': 10/60,
    'CAT2': 2,
    'CAT3': 10/60,
    'CAT4': 8*60,
    'CAT5': 10/60
}

df['TIME'] = df['CATEGORY'].map(complexity)

df['AGENT'].value_counts() * df.groupby('AGENT')['TIME'].sum()

# AGENT
# A      17.000000
# B       8.000000
# C    1929.333333
# dtype: float64
```

Have you guys encountered a similar subject ? I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: I see you just edited to add value_counts * groupby.sum. What would be the rationale to have a value_counts at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're now using a quantitative value, `value_counts` is no longer appropriate, better use a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby('AGENT', sort=False)['TIME'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
AGENT
C    482.333333
B      4.000000
A      2.833333
Name: TIME, dtype: float64
```

Or if you want to have the productivity relative to the total number of tasks, then a `mean`:

```
df.groupby('AGENT', sort=False)['TIME'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
AGENT
C    120.583333
B      2.000000
A      0.472222
Name: TIME, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have a small question. Your two solutions gives the same final ordering. Can you explain please what's the difference between them ? And what's wrong with my approach ?

Comment: The same final ordering here is by chance, this might not always be the case as the sum and mean are two different indicators. Someone doing a lot of small tasks might rank top compared to someone performing only one big task, but will rank low when using the mean? It all depends on what you're trying to rank. I'd say the sum might make more sense.